# Chrome extension throwing a "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building an extension that will store a token from a chrome tab (it will take the token once you finish loading that particular tab).
When running the extension (It is run by a press of the button) it is supposed to "get" the token and use it to create an ajax call.

This is a simple explanation of what it does; this is the code:

background.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [
                new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                    pageUrl: { urlContains: 'h' }
                })
            ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
        }]);
    });
});
```

manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Page action by URL",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Shows a page action for urls which have the letter 'g' in them.",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon32.png",
    "default_title": "linkedin URL!",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js" : ["getToken.js"],
        "run_at":"document_end"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "cookies",
    "declarativeContent",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "icons" : {
    "48" : "images/icon32.png",
    "128" : "images/icon32.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

getToken.js: [Content script]

```
if(document.getElementById('HrmsTkn')){
        chrome.storage.local.set({ 'HrmsTkn': document.getElementById('HrmsTkn').value});
        chrome.storage.local.get('HrmsTkn', function(result){
            alert('Got it' + result.HrmsTkn);
        });
   }
```

and popup.js (button activation function):

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnGetHtml').click(function () {
        var token;
        chrome.storage.local.get('HrmsTkn', function (items) {
             if(items){
                token = items.HrmsTkn;  
             }
        });
    try {
            alert(token);
        }
    catch(e) {
        }
   });
});
```

I get the following error in devTools and undefined alerted once the button is clicked, also I checked the storage area of the extension using StorageAreaExtension which shows the extension has the value I'm trying to get.

And when I debug it, in the storage.local.get function, it throws the following error:

> Lazy require of extension.binding did not set the binding field
>   extensions::lastError:82: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined
>   or null to object{TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to
>   object

Any ideas why? I've looked up google for the past few days but did not find any reliable fix.

Comment: chrome.* API methods that may accept a function callback are asynchronous so the actual work is performed when the current code context finishes, thus `get` starts to look for the value before `set` actually sets it (storage access has several async steps internally). Also, you've declared the content script that gets injected on all pages regardless of PageStateMatcher.

Comment: I've had this exception occur to me even though the token had not even been cleared and was there since last run.. so I find your explanation a bit lacking, the only time it didn't throw an exception was after I had cleaned the previous data..but.. for some weird reason it's not consistent in its behavior.

Comment: Ahem, my comment also applies to the popup: you're trying to display the value not yet retrieved outside of the callback.

Comment: That makes sense, Okay, I'll test whether it's the case, although I guess it is considering I can't think of anything else. Thanks.

Comment: It is the case. This is how asynchronous JavaScript works.

Comment: Well, I added a 5 second delay to the alert part, still nothing. the exception thrown discontinues the get operation as I see it.

Comment: Also; this appears before any exception thrown: Lazy require of extension.binding did not set the binding field

Comment: See [Chrome extension storage.sync.set in content script throws exception](//stackoverflow.com/q/41197282)